# How to Output from Generic Array List, to Listbox?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, listbox

I am trying to output from Array list to a Listbox. My problem is I think is I do not know how to connect the Class to the Generic array list a made?  The end result should look like this:

[image]

And the information should be then sorted like so: all the information enters the first list box, and then the above 18 goes to adults, and the below 18 to kids. My class looks like this:

```
namespace Patients
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }

        public Person() //Constructor
        {
            Age = 0;
            Password = "";
        }

        public Person (string name, int age, string password) //Parameters    
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Age = age;
            this.Password = password;    
        }

        public override string ToString()  // 
        {    
            return Name + Age.ToString() + Password;  //outputs as a string
            // return Name + " (" + Age + " years) " + Password ;
        }               
    }
}    

namespace Patients
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person p = new Person();

            List<string> People = new List<string>();
            People.Add(TextBoxName.Text);
            People.Add(TextBoxAge.Text);
            People.Add(TextBoxPassword.Text);

            foreach (object Person in People)     
            {
                ListBoxAll.Items.Add(p.Name + p.Age.ToString() + p.Password);
            }

            if (p.Age > 18)
            {
                ListBoxAdults.Items.Add(p.Name + p.Age.ToString() + p.Password);    
            }                 
            else
            {    
                ListBoxKids.Items.Add(p.Name + p.Age.ToString() + p.Password);    
            }                        
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: do a google search on how to use the `string.Join()` function ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you don't set the Properties. In Fact you don't need a List at all, but you can use a List to keep hold of your patients. It's still not necessary though:

```
namespace Patients
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // Define Property and initialize List
    public List<Person> patients{ get; } = new List<Person>();
    public static void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
     public void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use the Constructor with Parameters 
        Person p = new Person(TextBoxName.Text, TextBoxAge.Text, TextBoxPassword.Text);
        // Add your patient to your List
        patients.Add(p);
        // Use the ToString() of your Person
        ListBoxAll.Items.Add(p.ToString());


        if (p.Age > 18)
        {
            ListBoxAdults.Items.Add(p.ToString());    
        }                 
        else
        {    
            ListBoxKids.Items.Add(p.ToString());    
        }                        
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: Our assignment requires we use a generic array list.  Thanks for the help... will keep trying..

Comment: An Array or a List?

Comment: I am still new to terms sorry if I interchange them.  We were told that  it was better to use List<T> Class.. then a Arraylist.   This was our resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing and matching a bit. 
Try something like this.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = TextBoxName.Text;
p.Age= TextBoxAge.Text;
p.Password= TextBoxPassword.Text;
ListBoxAll.Items.Add(p);
```

Comment: Note if you want them to be on seperate lines like in your example you can do ListBoxAll>items.Add(p.Name); ListBoxAll>items.Add(p.Age); ListBoxAll>items.Add(p.Password);

Comment: You can´t add a `Person` to a listbox and expect it to print something valid (unless you consider `Patients.Person` to be a valid entry within your listbox).

Comment: Yes you can, you can even just add a string. If you add an object it will use the "toString" for the object for printing, which is what he wants based on his example

Answer (score 0):

A few tricks that are nice to us, first off you can declare defaults for properties like so:

```
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Steve";
    public int Age { get; set; } = 1;
    public String Password { get; set; } = "password";
```

However, it should also be noted that "" is the default for strings already and 0 is the default for non-nullable int, so you don't even need to worrying about those default values.

Declaring `Age = 0;` in the constructor is basically a waste of time in this case. (If it was a nullable int however the default is `null`)

Next up, since you are okay with defaults, you don't need to declare properties in the constructor like you are.

You can completely remove the constructor and just do the following:

```
 var myPerson = new Person { Name = "Steve", Age = 18, Password = "Foo" };
```

Next up, you are losing all your existing people as soon as you exit the scope of the button click.

Instead you'll want to declare two lists of people outside the scope of the click method (that way they persist), something like "Adults" and "Children"

Then perhaps make a method called "PopulateLists" that would do the following:

1. Clear all list boxes
2. Add to each box the list of each groups names that apply (you can make an IQueryable by using Linq and Select statements on your list)

When you click the button, you should make a new person, assign it to the right list, then call PopulateLists()

Here's the info you need to get started:

Linq selection to get list of properties (in this case Im going to turn a List of People into a List of Ages, you can do the same with names though)

```
 var ages = People.Select(p => p.Age);
```

The .Items property of a ListBox works the same as a list, it just visually shows itself. It's a list of strings specifically.

So for example you can do things like...

```
 MyListBox.Items.Clear();
 MyListBox.Items.Add(...);
 MyListBox.Items.AddRange(...);
```

etc etc.

That should get you started!